# API Management - Policy Debugging

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, api-gateway

I'm having some trouble debugging policies through the Visual Studio Code extensions.
Whenever clicking on the test operation button the HTTP rest-client extension opens.
The extension presets your HTTP call to be executed however, the versioning scheme is automatically defined as a template parameter instead of a query parameter (api-version=v2.4)
There is no possibility to amend it in the settings of visual studio code. (extension)

[image]

[image]

Whenever clicking the start policy debugging

[image]

The debugging starts but is unsuccessful to connect.
I can clearly see the debugging logs where the client tries to connect however it is failing to do so because of a gateway error.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The APIM must be on Developer tier to be able to debug policies